1D 'Clustering'
I’m working on a research paper about a robust federated learning aggregation scheme to defend against attackers.
I have a 1D array of trust scores for clients, and I need to cluster them to identify honest clients (highest scores). Typically, attackers (around 5–20% of the total) have similar trust scores, and visually, their cluster is often distinct from the rest.
Currently, I’m using DBSCAN and KDE, where the eps (for DBSCAN) and the bandwidth (for KDE) are fixed but increase with each iteration. However, a single fixed value only works well in specific scenarios; in others, smaller or larger values are required for optimal performance.
I’ve also tried HDBSCAN, but it didn’t perform well in this context.
Do you have suggestions on how to handle this clustering problem more effectively?

Hard to say without seeing the data. Have you considererd outlier detection or (k)-Nearest Neighbours?

Rather than using a fixed value for DBSCAN's neighbourhood radius eps=, perhaps you could run a search for the 'optimal' value each time?
It could work as follows, each time you want to cluster a new dataset:

Evaluate a range of $\epsilon$ values, i.e. DBSCAN(eps=...). For each eps=, record the following:

silhouette_score(), calinski_harabasz_score(), and the DBCV score. The latter is density-based and preferable for DBSCAN.

These indicate how cohesive and well-separated the clustering is


The number of "noise" points (labelled as -1 by DBSCAN)

Fewer "noise" points means more points have a cluster assignment


The number of clusters found by DBSCAN

Prefer fewer clusters but only to the extent they optimise the other scores




Pick the eps= that optimises over the measures above.


Note that a ground-truth is not required for this particular approach.
The idea is that these metrics push eps= towards clusters that are internally cohesive and well-separated, with most points assigned a label, and enough clusters to meaningfully partition the space without splitting things further.
This approach is based on that described in Hands-on Unsupervised Learning with Python, Giuseppe Bonaccorso, Packt Publishing, 2019.
